# android captured video quality is poor and error while buffering video

Tags: java, android

I am creating a simple app, which could preview the camera view in half of the screen and capture video, but I have a problem with buffering video and video quality (the video quality is very low, after saving it to file). After pressing button "Stop record", my app crash and showing below error:

```
    I/CameraDeviceState: Legacy camera service transitioning to state CAPTURING
E/IMGSRV: :0: WSEGL_GetDrawableParameters: Failed to obtain minimal parameters
E/IMGSRV: :0: KEGLGetDrawableParameters: Native window is invalid
E/libEGL: eglMakeCurrent:800 error 300b (EGL_BAD_NATIVE_WINDOW)
E/CameraDeviceGLThread-0: Received exception on GL render thread: 
                          java.lang.IllegalStateException: makeCurrent: EGL error: 0x300b
                              at android.hardware.camera2.legacy.SurfaceTextureRenderer.checkEglError(SurfaceTextureRenderer.java:530)
                              at android.hardware.camera2.legacy.SurfaceTextureRenderer.makeCurrent(SurfaceTextureRenderer.java:518)
                              at android.hardware.camera2.legacy.SurfaceTextureRenderer.drawIntoSurfaces(SurfaceTextureRenderer.java:721)
                              at android.hardware.camera2.legacy.GLThreadManager$1.handleMessage(GLThreadManager.java:105)
                              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
                              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                              at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
I/CameraDeviceState: Legacy camera service transitioning to state ERROR
E/RequestThread-0: Timed out while waiting for request to complete.
W/CaptureCollector: Preview buffers dropped for request: 1
E/CameraDeviceState: Cannot receive result while in state: 0
E/CameraDeviceState: Cannot receive result while in state: 0
E/CameraDeviceState: Cannot receive result while in state: 0
E/BufferQueueProducer: [SurfaceTexture-1-24067-2] cancelBuffer: BufferQueue has been abandoned
E/BufferQueueProducer: [SurfaceTexture-1-24067-2] cancelBuffer: BufferQueue has been abandoned
E/BufferQueueProducer: [SurfaceTexture-1-24067-2] cancelBuffer: BufferQueue has been abandoned
E/BufferQueueProducer: [SurfaceTexture-1-24067-2] cancelBuffer: BufferQueue has been abandoned
E/BufferQueueProducer: [SurfaceTexture-1-24067-2] cancelBuffer: BufferQueue has been abandoned
E/BufferQueueProducer: [SurfaceTexture-1-24067-2] cancelBuffer: BufferQueue has been abandoned
E/BufferQueueProducer: [SurfaceTexture-1-24067-2] cancelBuffer: BufferQueue has been abandoned
E/BufferQueueProducer: [SurfaceTexture-1-24067-2] cancelBuffer: BufferQueue has been abandoned
```

Code:

```
public class SecondActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final int REQUEST_CAMERA_PERMISSION_RESULT = 0;
    private static final int REQUEST_WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE_PERMISSION_RESULT = 0;

    private TextureView mTextureView;
    private TextureView.SurfaceTextureListener mSurfaceTextureListener = new TextureView.SurfaceTextureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onSurfaceTextureAvailable(SurfaceTexture surface, int width, int height) {
            setupCamera(width, height);
            connectCamera();
        }

        @Override
        public void onSurfaceTextureSizeChanged(SurfaceTexture surface, int width, int height) {

        }

        @Override
        public boolean onSurfaceTextureDestroyed(SurfaceTexture surface) {
            if (mMediaRecorder != null) {
                mMediaRecorder.stop();
                mMediaRecorder.release();
                mMediaRecorder = null;
            }
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public void onSurfaceTextureUpdated(SurfaceTexture surface) {

        }
    };
    private CameraDevice mCameraDevice;
    private CameraDevice.StateCallback mCameraDeviceStateCallback = new CameraDevice.StateCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onOpened(CameraDevice camera) {
            mCameraDevice = camera;

            /* if there is no record button */

            /*
            try {
                createVideoFileName();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            StartRecord();
            mMediaRecorder.start();
            */


            /* if there is record button */

            if (mIsRecording) {
                try {
                    createVideoFileName();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                StartRecord();
                mMediaRecorder.start();
            } else {
                startPreview();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onDisconnected(CameraDevice camera) {
            camera.close();
            mCameraDevice = null;
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(CameraDevice camera, int error) {
            camera.close();
            mCameraDevice = null;
        }
    };
    private HandlerThread mBackgroundHandlerThread;
    private Handler mBackgroundHandler;
    private String mCameraId;
    private Size mPreviewSize;
    private Size mVideoSize;
    private MediaRecorder mMediaRecorder;

    private int mTotalRotation;
    private CaptureRequest.Builder mCaptureRequestBuilder;
    private ImageButton mRecordImageButton;
    private boolean mIsRecording = false;

    private File mVideoFolder;
    private String mVideoFileName;

    private static SparseIntArray ORIENTATIONS = new SparseIntArray();

    static {
        ORIENTATIONS.append(Surface.ROTATION_0, 0);
        ORIENTATIONS.append(Surface.ROTATION_90, 90);
        ORIENTATIONS.append(Surface.ROTATION_180, 180);
        ORIENTATIONS.append(Surface.ROTATION_270, 270);
    }

    /**
     * ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
     * See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
     */
    private GoogleApiClient client;

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();// ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
// See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
        client.connect();
        // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
        // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
        AppIndex.AppIndexApi.start(client, getIndexApiAction());
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();// ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
// See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
        AppIndex.AppIndexApi.end(client, getIndexApiAction());
        // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
        // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
        client.disconnect();
    }

    /**
     * ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
     * See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
     */
    public Action getIndexApiAction() {
        Thing object = new Thing.Builder()
                .setName("Second Page") // TODO: Define a title for the content shown.
                // TODO: Make sure this auto-generated URL is correct.
                .setUrl(Uri.parse("http://[ENTER-YOUR-URL-HERE]"))
                .build();
        return new Action.Builder(Action.TYPE_VIEW)
                .setObject(object)
                .setActionStatus(Action.STATUS_TYPE_COMPLETED)
                .build();
    }

    private static class CompareSizeByArea implements Comparator<Size> {
        @Override
        public int compare(Size lhs, Size rhs) {
            return Long.signum((long) lhs.getWidth() * lhs.getHeight() /
                    (long) rhs.getWidth() * rhs.getHeight());
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);

        createVideoFolder();
        mMediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
        mTextureView = (TextureView) findViewById(R.id.cameraView);
        mRecordImageButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.videoOnlineImageButton);
        mRecordImageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (mIsRecording) {
                    //createVideoFolder();
                    mIsRecording = false;
                    mMediaRecorder.stop();
                    mMediaRecorder.reset();
                    //startPreview();
                } else {
                    //createVideoFolder();
                    mIsRecording = true;
                    checkWriteStoragePermission();
                }
            }
        });


        /* To stop recording */
        /*
        mMediaRecorder.stop();
        mMediaRecorder.reset();
        startPreview();
        */
        // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
        // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
        client = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this).addApi(AppIndex.API).build();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        startBackgroundThread();

        if (mTextureView.isAvailable()) {
            setupCamera(mTextureView.getWidth(), mTextureView.getHeight());
            connectCamera();
        } else {
            mTextureView.setSurfaceTextureListener(mSurfaceTextureListener);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_CAMERA_PERMISSION_RESULT) {
            if (grantResults[0] != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Application will not run without camera services", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE_PERMISSION_RESULT) {
            if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                // Start recording

                //
                try {
                    createVideoFileName();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                // Starts
                Toast.makeText(this,
                        "Permission successfully granted!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this,
                        "App needs to save video to run", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        closeCamera();
        stopBackgroundThread();
        super.onPause();
    }

    private void setupCamera(int width, int height) {
        CameraManager cameraManager = (CameraManager) getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE);
        try {
            for (String cameraId : cameraManager.getCameraIdList()) {
                CameraCharacteristics cameraCharateristics = cameraManager.getCameraCharacteristics(cameraId);
                if (cameraCharateristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.LENS_FACING) ==
                        CameraCharacteristics.LENS_FACING_FRONT) {
                    continue;
                }
                StreamConfigurationMap map = cameraCharateristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.SCALER_STREAM_CONFIGURATION_MAP);
                int deviceOrientation = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation();
                mTotalRotation = sensorToDeviceRotation(cameraCharateristics, deviceOrientation);
                boolean swapRotation = mTotalRotation == 90 || mTotalRotation == 270;
                int rotatedWidth = width;
                int rotatedHeight = height;
                if (swapRotation) {
                    rotatedWidth = height;
                    rotatedHeight = width;
                }
                mPreviewSize = chooseOptimalSize(map.getOutputSizes(SurfaceTexture.class), rotatedWidth, rotatedHeight);
                mVideoSize = chooseOptimalSize(map.getOutputSizes(MediaRecorder.class), rotatedWidth, rotatedHeight);
                mCameraId = cameraId;
                return;
            }
        } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    private void connectCamera() {
        CameraManager cameraManager = (CameraManager) getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE);
        try {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.CAMERA) ==
                        PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    cameraManager.openCamera(mCameraId, mCameraDeviceStateCallback, mBackgroundHandler);
                } else {
                    if (shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(android.Manifest.permission.CAMERA)) {
                        Toast.makeText(this, "Video app required access to camera", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    requestPermissions(new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.CAMERA}, REQUEST_CAMERA_PERMISSION_RESULT);
                }
            } else {
                cameraManager.openCamera(mCameraId, mCameraDeviceStateCallback, mBackgroundHandler);
            }
        } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    private void StartRecord() {

        try {
            setupMediaRecorder();
            SurfaceTexture surfaceTexture = mTextureView.getSurfaceTexture();
            surfaceTexture.setDefaultBufferSize(mPreviewSize.getWidth(), mPreviewSize.getHeight());
            Surface previewSurface = new Surface(surfaceTexture);
            Surface recordSurface = mMediaRecorder.getSurface();
            mCaptureRequestBuilder = mCameraDevice.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_RECORD);
            mCaptureRequestBuilder.addTarget(previewSurface);
            mCaptureRequestBuilder.addTarget(recordSurface);

            mCameraDevice.createCaptureSession(Arrays.asList(previewSurface, recordSurface),
                    new CameraCaptureSession.StateCallback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onConfigured(CameraCaptureSession session) {
                            try {
                                session.setRepeatingRequest(
                                        mCaptureRequestBuilder.build(), null, null
                                );
                            } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onConfigureFailed(CameraCaptureSession session) {

                        }
                    }, null);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    private void startPreview() {
        SurfaceTexture surfaceTexture = mTextureView.getSurfaceTexture();
        surfaceTexture.setDefaultBufferSize(mPreviewSize.getWidth(), mPreviewSize.getHeight());
        Surface previewSurface = new Surface(surfaceTexture);

        try {
            mCaptureRequestBuilder = mCameraDevice.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_PREVIEW);
            mCaptureRequestBuilder.addTarget(previewSurface);

            mCameraDevice.createCaptureSession(Arrays.asList(previewSurface),
                    new CameraCaptureSession.StateCallback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onConfigured(CameraCaptureSession cameraCaptureSession) {
                            try {
                                cameraCaptureSession.setRepeatingRequest(mCaptureRequestBuilder.build(),
                                        null, mBackgroundHandler);
                            } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onConfigureFailed(CameraCaptureSession cameraCaptureSession) {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Unable to setup camera preview", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }, null);

        } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void closeCamera() {
        if (mCameraDevice != null) {
            mCameraDevice.close();
            mCameraDevice = null;
        }
    }

    private void startBackgroundThread() {
        mBackgroundHandlerThread = new HandlerThread("Camera2VideoImage");
        mBackgroundHandlerThread.start();
        mBackgroundHandler = new Handler(mBackgroundHandlerThread.getLooper());
    }

    private void stopBackgroundThread() {
        mBackgroundHandlerThread.quitSafely();
        try {
            mBackgroundHandlerThread.join();
            mBackgroundHandlerThread = null;
            mBackgroundHandler = null;
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private static int sensorToDeviceRotation(CameraCharacteristics cameraCharacteristics, int deviceOrientation) {
        int sensorOrientation = cameraCharacteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.SENSOR_ORIENTATION);
        deviceOrientation = ORIENTATIONS.get(deviceOrientation);
        return (sensorOrientation + deviceOrientation + 360) % 360;
    }

    private static Size chooseOptimalSize(Size[] choices, int width, int height) {
        List<Size> bigEnough = new ArrayList<Size>();
        for (Size option : choices) {
            if (option.getHeight() == option.getWidth() * height / width &&
                    option.getWidth() >= width && option.getHeight() >= height) {
                bigEnough.add(option);
            }
        }
        if (bigEnough.size() > 0) {
            return Collections.min(bigEnough, new CompareSizeByArea());
        } else {
            return choices[0];
        }
    }

    private void createVideoFolder() {
        File movieFile = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_MOVIES);
        mVideoFolder = new File(movieFile, "camera2VideoImage");
        if (!mVideoFolder.exists()) {
            mVideoFolder.mkdirs();
        }
    }

    private File createVideoFileName() throws IOException {
        // Vardas į failo pavadinimą
        //String timestamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
        String prepend = "VIDEO";
        File videoFile = File.createTempFile(prepend, ".mp4", mVideoFolder);
        mVideoFileName = videoFile.getAbsolutePath();
        return videoFile;
    }

    private void checkWriteStoragePermission() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                    == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                try {
                    createVideoFileName();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                StartRecord();
                mMediaRecorder.start();
            } else {
                if (shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "App needs to be able to save videos", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                requestPermissions(new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, REQUEST_WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE_PERMISSION_RESULT);
            }
        else {
            // Start recording
            mIsRecording = true;
            //
            try {
                createVideoFileName();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            StartRecord();
            mMediaRecorder.start();
        }
    }

    private void setupMediaRecorder() throws IOException {
        mMediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.SURFACE);
        mMediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
        mMediaRecorder.setOutputFile(mVideoFileName);
        mMediaRecorder.setAudioEncodingBitRate(1000000);
        mMediaRecorder.setVideoFrameRate(30);
        mMediaRecorder.setVideoSize(mVideoSize.getWidth(), mVideoSize.getHeight());
        mMediaRecorder.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.H264);
        mMediaRecorder.setOrientationHint(mTotalRotation);
        mMediaRecorder.prepare();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
mIsRecording = false;
mMediaRecorder.stop();
mMediaRecorder.reset();
//startPreview();
```

it may works after change the code like this:

```
mIsRecording = false;
startPreview();
mMediaRecorder.stop();
mMediaRecorder.reset();
```

cuz if stop the mediarecorder directly. the data source(camera) will still send datas to it and this may cause some errors. so we gotta stop the cameracapturesession before we stop the mediarecorder.